# Weird gradle error - Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

Getting a weird gradle error here in android studio, and it's something I haven't gotten until I added an animation folder in my res directory. In this folder I have one animation file with

tags and one alpha sub tag set.

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':FullerUV:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Need more logs. That error could be occurred when resource files are malformed.

Comment: Did you run it with --info or --debug? This can give you a hint.

Comment: That's my next question. How exactly do I go about doing that?

Comment: Run `./gradlew compileDebug --debug` from the command line or upgrade Android Studio to 0.4.1 and follow the first item under "Gradle IDE integration" from: http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio041released

Comment: Also, what is the name of the file in the animation folder? `res` files have strict naming conventions (e.g. no dashes, only underscores)

Comment: Thanks, I will run that in just a moment. I tried naming the animation folder the following:

anim
animation
animator

All throwing the same error

Comment: Can you post your project file structure screenshot with file name inside that.

Comment: Post your build.gradle file, specifically the sourcesets { } section.  In my case it was caused by res.srcDirs = ['res'].

Answer (score 0):

This is the way your anim and files inside look like :

[image]

I think names are correct else you will be ended up error like this

```
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':YourPocket:mergeDebugResources'.
  > PROJECT_DIR\src\main\res\anim\slide_in-    right.xml: Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

  * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
```

Make sure you are writing the correct animation try compiling after deleting the animation files in anim dir or change the content in file with text given below. Keep anim directory.

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
 </set>
```

If it work fine then include your animation file text in question.